# In SqlAlchemy using expunge_all with an AsyncSession throws sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using `AsyncSession` like:

```
default_session_factory = sessionmaker(
    create_async_engine(Settings().get_postgres_uri(), future=True), # echo=True
    expire_on_commit=False,
    class_=AsyncSession,
)

session: AsyncSession = default_session_factory()
```

and in one of my functions, since I wanted to further access to retrieved objects, I used `session.expunge_all()`. It works and I can access those instances but I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called;
can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?
```

I guess it's because of using a sync function, aka `expunge_all` but am not sure and how to  work it around